# nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet annotation contains invalid word location

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am new to kubernetes and using AWS EKS cluster 1.21. I am trying to write the nginx ingress config for my k8s cluster and blocking some request using **server-snippet**. My ingress config is below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abc-ingress-external
  namespace: backend
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-external
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
       location = /ping {
         deny all;
         return 403;
       }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev-abc.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
              name: miller
              port:
                number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

When I apply this config, I get this error:

```
for: "ingress.yml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet annotation contains invalid word location
```

I looked into this and got this is something related to ***annotation-value-word-blocklist***. However i don't know how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there's [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5738#issuecomment-971799464) using `location` with some versions. The following was tested successfully on EKS cluster.

Install basic ingress-nginx on EKS:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml`

**Note:** If your cluster version is < 1.21, you need to comment out `ipFamilyPolicy` and `ipFamilies` in the service spec.

Run a http service:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/docs/examples/http-svc.yaml`

Create an ingress for the service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-svc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
       location = /ping {
         deny all;
         return 403;
       }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Return 200 as expected:
`curl -H 'HOST: test.domain.com' http://<get your nlb address from the console>`

Return 200 as expected:
`curl -H 'HOST: test.domain.com' -k https://<get your nlb address from the console>`

Return 403 as expected, the snippet is working:
`curl -H 'HOST: test.domain.com' -k https://<get your nlb address from the console>/ping`

[image]

Use the latest release to avoid the "annotation contains invalid word location" issue.

Comment: Thanks @gohm'c for the response. But it's still showing same error.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.

Comment: My cluster version is EKS 1.21 and i deleted my old nginx controller and followed all the steps that you had given but it is still showing me the same error.
```Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "ingress.yml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet annotation contains invalid word location```

Comment: Thanks @gohm'c this worked for me. It was my old internal ingress which causing the issue but after deletion of that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, replacing `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` by `nginx.org/server-snippets` fixed the issue for me. See for instance [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/)